# Meaning of triple particle (?) のはな

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の

> そういうのはな(noun)だったらこう｡｡｡

I'm not sure what to make of the のはな part. I'm not even sure they're all particles. I suspect the な might be a negative. I'm guessing the の turns the first word into a noun, like "that sort". So, maybe it's saying "If that sort of (noun) wasn't こう..." But, I'm not familiar with a word こう. 子, yes, but...

The context is, a character talking to another character after thinking about the other forgetting to cut his hair. Full bubble: だったらさ! そういうのはな男だったらこう｡｡｡ The other person then seems taken aback.

Comment: It's still way too vague. ”はな” could just be a word written without Kanji, possibly even two words... Might also be something related to the piece you're reading. If you could perhaps link us to the page or something, we could really help you out more here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pronoun の, particle は and interjectional particle な.

そういうの : such things

は (topic particle)

な (filler)

男だったら : if you're a man

こう : this way

Comment: So, it would translate something like:

Come on! Doing such things this way if you're a man is...

Comment: こう can also function as a filler. I might translate it as "For a man, those things are... (こう = 'how should I put it...')", but it really depends on the context.