# what is the meaning of "みたいなな" in below sentence?

Tags: particle-な

I'm watching a Japanese TV drama. I don't understand the meaning of"みたいなな" in this conversation :"お前らみたいなな  チャラチャラウニャ~みたいのがな世の中ダメにすんだ分かったか-?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お前らみたいな is an adjectival phrase meaning "like you guys". The second な right after it is a filler particle meaning nothing. It's the same as the な you see before 世の中.

- [What do 「はな」 and 「いうとな」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27999/5010)
- [Meaning of triple particle (?) のはな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30042/5010)
- [What is the にはな used for in the following sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72490/5010)

> お前らみたいな(な)、チャラチャラウニャ～みたいのが(な)、世の中ダメにすんだ、分かったか。
> チャラチャラウニャ-ish people like you guys are the ones who ruin this world, you understand?

な in parentheses are fillers, and they can be dropped or replaced with よ, さ, etc. チャラチャラウニャ is an unique mimesis, but I think it probably describes frivolousness ([chara](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5094/5010)) and laziness.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Mitaina みたいな means "like." The speaker is starting the sentence with "A bunch of chara-chara unya like you..." and the speaker probably repeated the な while (acting like they were) thinking about how to end the sentence but too angry to think quietly.

Comment: thank you very much